# Electron + typescript + i18next problem - i18next::backendConnector [...] fs.readFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, types, electron, i18next

I've spent almost whole day on trying to configure i18next translations in electron + typescript. I actually have no idea what can i do with it to make it work. I always get the following error: "i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function".

for boilderplate i've used https://github.com/diego3g/electron-typescript-react

i18n.config file (locales are in same folder and structured: locales/*lang*/*namespace*

```
import i18next, { InitOptions } from 'i18next'
import backend from 'i18next-fs-backend'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
export const DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = 'common'

const i18nOptions: InitOptions = {
  lng: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
  fallbackLng: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
  defaultNS: DEFAULT_NAMESPACE,
  fallbackNS: DEFAULT_NAMESPACE,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  debug: true,
  backend: {
    loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    addPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json',
  },
}

i18next.use(backend).use(initReactI18next).init(i18nOptions)

export default i18next
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
var i18nextPlugin = require('ya-i18next-webpack-plugin').default

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'), 'node_modules'],
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: require('./rules.webpack'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new i18nextPlugin({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      defaultNamespace: 'common',
      languages: ['en', 'pl'],
      functionName: '_t',
      resourcePath: '..public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    }),
  ],
}
```

i18n initialization:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'
import { i18n } from './config'

i18n.init()

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In electron you need to use IPC (inter-process-communication) to request a file be read or written from the electron's main process.
So there is no direct fs (filesystem) access.

Try this i18next backend plugin instead: https://github.com/reZach/i18next-electron-fs-backend